# Ckeckbox inside menu actions in flutter is not updated until I reopen the menu again

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-bloc

Here is the relevant part of code:

```
class QuestionsScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  QuestionsScreenState createState() => QuestionsScreenState();
}

    class QuestionsScreenState extends State<QuestionsScreen> {
      final List<Question> questions = [];
      bool offline = false;
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return BlocProvider(
          create: (context) => QuestionsBloc(sl.get<QuestionsRepository>())
            ..add(QuestionsInitialLoad()),
          child: Scaffold(
            appBar: AppBar(
              title: Text('StackOverflow Questions'),
              centerTitle: true,
              actions: <Widget>[
                PopupMenuButton<int>(
                    itemBuilder: (BuildContext context) => <PopupMenuItem<int>>[
                          new PopupMenuItem<int>(value: 1, child: Text('Refresh')),
                          new PopupMenuItem<int>(
                              value: 2,
                              child: new Row(children: <Widget>[
                                new Text("Offline"),
                                new Checkbox(
                                  value: offline,
                                  onChanged: (newValue) {
                                    setState(() {
                                      offline = newValue!;
                                    });
                                  }, //  <-- leading Checkbox
                                )
                              ])),
                        ],
                    onSelected: (int value) {
                      setState(() {
                        if (value == 1) {
                          questions.clear();
                          QuestionsBloc(sl.get<QuestionsRepository>())
                            ..add
                            ..isFetching = true
                            ..add(QuestionsRestart());
                        }
                      });
                    })
              ],
            ),
            body: QuestionsBody(questions, offline),
          ),
        );
      }
    }
```

As you can see, I have a checkbox declared inside the pop menu actions button of the scaffold appbar in flutter. When I click on it, the update happens, but I cannot see the update until I reopen the menu again. It is possible to see the update of the checkbox in the popup menu right away? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how it looks on dev-tools after clicking `PopupMenuButton`

[image]

`PopupMenuItem` is not within the current context.

We can use [StatefulBuilder](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/StatefulBuilder-class.html) to handle cases like this, In this case wrap `CheckBox` with `StatefulBuilder`. You can also choose on `Row`.

```dart
StatefulBuilder(
    builder: (context, setStateSB) => Checkbox(
          value: offline,
          onChanged: (newValue) {
            setStateSB(() {
              offline = newValue!; // to update checkbox
            });
            setState(() {
              offline = newValue!; //to update the main ui if needed
            });
          },
        )),
```